# Little oh notation

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, computational-complexity

The GNFS-function $f(n)$ with $n$ the number for which we search the factorisation shows the complexity of that factorisation:

\begin{align}
f(n) = e^{\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}} + o(1)\right)\left(\ln n\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \left(\ln\ln n\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}
\end{align}

**What is the meaning and value of $o(1)$?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Relevant: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/what-is-worst-case-complexity-of-number-field-sieve

Answer (score 1):

It means, [by definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html): "which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$."

Now, for the value... it could be any function converging to $0$. In this particular case, you could try to get more information about this low-order term, but without more information we cannot say anything else.

Comment: for n big, the factor o(1) ln(n)^1/3 (ln ln n)^2/3 does not exist.  for n small, the factor o(1) ln(n)^1/3 (ln ln n)^2/3 exists. But how can i understand the value for o(1) in this case?

Comment: I don't understand the question in your comment. Think of $o(1)$ as "$g(n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)=0$." It's literally what that means.

Comment: ok, but what is the meaning of o(1) for small values of n?

Comment: Well, it could be anything, literally. This is only an asymptotic statement.

Comment: Ok strange, so you can only say that that part of the equation becomes 0 for large values of n

Comment: Not "becomes" $0$ -- tends to $0$. But it's the same with **all** asymptotics: an $O(n)$-time algorithm can be pretty bad for small values of $n$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Given two functions $h, g \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, in general $h \in o(g)$ means  that for every choice of a constant $k > 0$, you can find a constant $a$ such that the inequality $0 \leq h(n) < k \, g(n)$ holds for all $n > a$.

Here, $1$ stands for the constant function $g(n) = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $o(1)$ in your expression stands for any function $h \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that, for every choice of a constant $k > 0$ there is a constant $a$ such that $0 \leq h(n) < k$ holds for all $n > a$. In other words, $\lim_{n \to \infty} h(n) = 0$.

Comment: for n big, the factor o(1) ln(n)^1/3 (ln ln n)^2/3 does not exist.  for n small, the factor o(1) ln(n)^1/3 (ln ln n)^2/3 exists. But how can i understand the value for o(1) in this case?